# Access custom widget parameters from helper

Tags: blocks, helper, widgets

I have a widget where I need to get a parameter from user and then be able to use it inside my Helper/Data.php file.

The widget looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widgets>
    <my_product_reviews type="reviewcontainer/product_container">
        <name>My Review Container</name>
        <description>Displays the product reviews for a given product in a widget</description>
        <query_reviews_by>
            <label>Get product reviews by</label>
            <type>select</type>
            <values>
                <product_id translate="label">
                    <label>Product ID</label>
                    <value>id</value>
                </product_id>
                <product_sku translate="label">
                    <label>Product SKU</label>
                    <value>sku</value>
                </product_sku>
            </values>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <visible>1</visible>
            <required>1</required>
        </query_reviews_by>
```

I can access this params from my Block/Product/Container:

```
<?php

class My_Reviewcontainer_Block_Product_Container extends Mage_Core_Block_Template implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface
{
    /**
     *
     * Returns the parameter set on the widget for: query_reviews_by
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getParamQueryReviewsBy()
    {
        if ($queryReviewsBy = $this->getData('query_reviews_by')) {
            return $queryReviewsBy;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

But how can I access it from my Helper:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class My_ReviewContainer_Helper_Data
 */
class My_ReviewContainer_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{    
    /**
     * The constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
       // here for example
   }
..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some Magento books and tuts.. I found out that I should move the methods on the `Data.php` into a model because `Data.php` is just a helper class of the module and most of the time its just empty but **required**!

So now in my templates, I call the block `Block\Product\Container.php` which calls the model using `Mage::getModel('my_model_name_here',$params)`.. The params array contain the data I get from `$this->getData()`